# Subtract one time from another - bash

Tags: bash, time, awk, subtraction

I have a text file that contains date, and two time-strings separated by spaces (a lot of these) in the format as given below:

```
2011-03-05 15:16:41 15:16:42
```

My question is this:
Using awk, how can I separate the time instants, assign them to variables and then subtract them? The answer to the above string would be something like:

```
2011-03-05 0:0:1
```

The text file is made up of a lot of lines of the above format.

I have gone through SO and see that there are a lot of date and time arithmetic questions, but none that would seem to fit to this particular requirement.

Any help is most welcome,
Sriram

Comment: Do you have `gawk` (which has time functions)?

Comment: @Dennis: how do I check that? I am working on GNU Awk v. 3.1.6a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple awk script which does not use any time functions:

```
$ cat subtract.awk

{
hh1=substr($2,1,2);
mm1=substr($2,4,2);
ss1=substr($2,7,2);

hh2=substr($3,1,2);
mm2=substr($3,4,2);
ss2=substr($3,7,2);

time1=hh1*60*60 + mm1*60 + ss1;
time2=hh2*60*60 + mm2*60 + ss2;

diff=time2-time1;

printf "%s %d:%d:%d\n",$1,diff/(60*60),diff%(60*60)/60,diff%60;
}
```

The input data:

```
$ cat file.txt
2011-03-05 15:16:41 15:16:42
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f subtract.awk < file.txt

2011-03-05 0:0:1
```

---

**Alternatively**, you can use `mktime`:

```
{
    date=$1
    gsub(/[-:]/," "); 
    diff=mktime ($1" "$2" "$3" "$7" "$8" "$9) - mktime ($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6);  
    printf "%s %d:%d:%d\n",date,diff/(60*60),diff%(60*60)/60,diff%60;
}
```

Comment: I dont have mktime, but the awk function solution worked real well!! Thanks!

Comment: Simpler? `awk '{date = $1; ymd = gensub("-", " ", "g", $1); diff = mktime( ymd " " gensub(":", " ", $2)) - mktime( ymd " " gensub(":", " ", $3)); printf...`

Answer (score 1):

For time arithmetic, I find it's easier to use a language with built-in time functions.  For example, in Tcl

```
set line "2011-03-05 15:16:41 15:16:42"
lassign [split $line] date time1 time2
set base [clock scan $date -format %Y-%m-%d]
set t1 [clock scan $time1 -format %T]
set t2 [clock scan $time2 -format %T]
set diff [expr {abs($t2 - $t1)}]
puts [clock format [clock add $base $diff seconds] -format "%Y-%m-%d %T"]
# ==> 2011-03-05 00:00:01
```